# Where can I find a fine-grained map of Lima indicating the crime level against non-Peruvian for each area, with the area being as precise as possible?

Tags: safety, maps, peru, lima

I am looking for a fine-grained map of Lima, Peru indicating the level of crimes against non-Peruvian citizens for each area, with the area being as precise as possible.

I would prefer a more fine-grained and comprehensive map, such as https://www.neighborhoodscout.com/ca/san-francisco/crime ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191221234649/https://www.neighborhoodscout.com/ca/san-francisco/crime)):

[image]

Comment: Would this map show anything other than where the tourists are staying, given how rare crime against tourists is in general? See [this relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1138/). Even if adjusted by the number of tourists per district it is unlikely to be statistically meaningful.

Comment: What makes you think such a map exists? Reading the article you linked to, the map you've given as an illustration is an aggregate of data from different organisations, each of whom uses different methodologies and ratings.

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica obviously such a map would need to be normalized. I would think that there are enough tourists and enough crimes in low tourist area to be statistically significant but if not I'm ok to remove the tourist requirements.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I gave an example of a more fine-grained and comprehensive map in the question. It seems to be reasonable that a similar map could be drawn for Lima. The map for Lima I show in the question is quite lossy compared to what is reasonable to assume the source data contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could find so far is http://www.newperuvian.com/most-dangerous-areas-of-lima-peru/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191221233746/http://www.newperuvian.com/most-dangerous-areas-of-lima-peru/)):

[image]

But it only ranks the worst 12 areas (which are [Lima districts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_districts_of_Lima)), and isn't more precise than the district level.

Reddit user [exim001](https://www.reddit.com/user/exim001) [pointed me](https://www.reddit.com/r/PERU/comments/efaidf/where_can_i_find_a_finegrained_map_of_lima/fdd32k1/)  to https://especiales.elcomercio.pe/?q=especiales/mapa-del-delito-ecpm/index.html:

> [This map] shows the crimes occurred in certain streets and districts of the capital.

[image]